# Numeric to binary filter in Weka

Tags: database, weka

I have csv data. I try to change one field from numeric to binary, But Numeric to binary filter apply for all indexes. How can I only apply it only for one index?

[My window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY1aN.png)

Comment: Where is the example code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set attribute indices accordingly. For example below command only change index 2.
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToBinary -R 2

1. Click to empty place near to NumericToBinary
2. Click to AttributeIndices empty place and write your attribute value.

[image]

Comment: In numeric to binary filter, there is no option to choose index

Comment: @Faraz which weka version are you using? As you can see from screnshot, there is a option to choose index.

Comment: I am using Weka 3.6 . Of course we must use this version in our college

Comment: @Faraz weka 3.6 has same attributeIndices parameter.

Comment: As you see in image there is no attributeIndices for this filter

Comment: @Faraz do you see black circle in the image? What is that? You are clicking wrong attribute (here ignoreClass). You need to click attributeIndices part.

Comment: i see black circle, If you see my image, there in no such a field, Its written in box numeric to binary! that ignore is on option for that

Comment: I wrote more information about how you can change that attribute value. That attribute value exists. You are clicking wrong place.

Comment: believe me :))) i am clicking to white space near numeric to binary, and it open generic object editor too

Answer (score 0):

You Didn't mentioned Sufficient details in question. But in any kind of relational databases you can access any cell just like accessing cell in 2d Array.You have to mention exact location(indices) to do that.

Comment: pls see the image ,there is no filed to mention exact index,

Answer (score 0):

[image].

you can set Discretize filter to use 2 bins.

Set makeBinary, useEqualFrequency to True and desiredWeightOfInstancesPerInterval accordingly